# Method is returning int type, but I keep getting "this method must return a result of type int" error

Tags: java, methods, types, return

This is the code:

```
private int getUpSite(int i, int j){
    if (i - 1 >= 1){
        if (grid[i - 2][j] != 0){
            return xyTo1D(i - 1, j);
        }
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Depending on the values of i and j, the method returns -1 or another integer built by the xyTo1D method. The problem is that the compiler keeps complaining: "this method must return a result of type int".

What is wrong with the code? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if control doesn't enter second level `if`?

```
if (grid[i - 2][j] != 0)
```

There is no return statement, isn't it?

You need to have a `return` statement for all possible paths.

*How do I fix this?*

One possible way:

Add `return` statement for first level if too. Example

```
if (i - 1 >= 1){
        if (grid[i - 2][j] != 0){
            return xyTo1D(i - 1, j);
        }
       return -1; //OR whatever int you would like to return
    }
```

Comment: Its not a good approach to use return at multiple blocks. Instead we should use a method level variable to return. We can set value in that.

Comment: @GV: There is big debate on this issue. Some people like to return from where ever business done, some would like to have return at end of the method. To be frank I don't want to jump into that discussion. As I said in my answer, this is one possible way and there are multiple ways one issue can be solved.

Comment: @GV:  That whole topic is 20 or 30 years old.  Don't tell me that someone resurrected it.  I thought it had been resolved when we also decided that methods should be short (which makes any `return` conspicuous).  What are the arguments of the discussion now?

Answer (score 1):

```
private int getUpSite(int i, int j){
int returnVal = -1;
    if (i - 1 >= 1){
        if (grid[i - 2][j] != 0){
            returnVal = xyTo1D(i - 1, j);
        }
    }
return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int getUpSite(int i, int j){   
    int returnValue=-1;   
    if (i - 1 >= 1 && grid[i - 2][j] != 0){
       returnValue = xyTo1D(i - 1, j);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```